# Compression error: Attempted to register and compress a file. The uncompressed version will be used instead

Tags: iis, ektron

I am finding the following warning in the event viewer:

> Timestamp: 12/15/2015 5:37:06 PM Message: Compression Error: Control
>   ID 'CB', of type 'ContentBlock,' in NamingContainer
>   'widgets_contentblock_ascx' attempted to register and compress a file
>   at path
>   "/WorkArea/FrameworkUI/js/Ektron/Controls/EktronUI/Editor/Aloha/lib/aloha-full.min.js"
>   using key '-328227864'.  The compression failed.  The uncompressed
>   version will be used instead. missing formal parameter Category:
>   Warning Priority: -1 EventId: 0 Severity: Warning Title: Machine:
>   DMZCMS12 Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130946739388625188
>   Process Id: 21044 Process Name: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   Win32 Thread Id: 10580 
>   Thread Name:  Extended Properties:

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can stop it?

Answer (score 0):

The system automatically combines & minifies JS files registered for use by Ektron controls. For some reason, that's failing to operate correctly on this file. Probably not a real problem on the compression side as it looks like the file is already minified.

More concerning is the fact that this is likely due to some error in the file itself - see: [Can't minify with Combres and yui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122253/cant-minify-with-combres-and-yui)

You can try replacing this file (in case it's corrupted) with the original from your Ektron install directory (default: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ektron\[Version]\StarterSites\CMS400min\...`).

Or it may be an issue in your version, which you've not specified, and one of the many Cumulative Updates or Service Packs would fix it.